# Eliminar "duplicados" pero antes concatenar sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola necesito eliminar datos repetidos pero si tienen diferente descripcion concatenar dicha descripcion
[image: Algo asi es lo que quiero no se si les sirve]

Answer (score 2):

podrías usar [STUFF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**LA SOLUCIÓN:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT nombre, 
                fecha, 
                (SELECT DISTINCT descipcion = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + descipcion 
                 FROM ListaNombres
                 where nombre = ln.nombre   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') ) as 
                 descripcion  
FROM ListaNombres ln
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es importante aclarar que STUFF no concatena cadenas, sino la insutrcción `FOR XML`. También es importante notar que hay un problema de rendimiento al usar DISTINCT y en su lugar se debería usar GROUP BY. Así se ejecuta la eliminación de duplicados y luego la concatenación, mientras que con DISTINCT es al revés y el trabajo se incrementa.

Comment: y si necesito insertar estos nuevos datos a la tabla una vez insertado deletear estos?